# Singapore visa - duration of stay

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, legal, singapore

I have a Singapore e-visa that expires on May 9. I want to enter on May 5 and stay for 10 days. I have read that normally passports are stamped for a 30 days stay. I would like to know if that would likely be the case, or if I'd only be allowed to stay for 4 days because of the visa expiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit vague from what I found, but you may be granted a stay beyond the validity of your visa (provided you show proof of return)

According to an [FAQ](http://www.ifaq.gov.sg/ICA/apps/fcd_faqmain.aspx?qst=2fN7e274RAp%2BbUzLdEL%2FmCxs7iwcgv8gv2atNDOvsLAhPwwiSKrfUTervh%2FukJ4ureCK2aaPz4DpM%2FgIAeYeR6SgRhqu9ItH4RyFVDD0tE7LfJx87ujs8%2F0xmctg4%2BnelVVocqBRpRXbsb50jrCuufitgpE5mly3MNYpZmSE9924VkpxI7mn9IcTLXYl0%2FiEd1wscoRHhC%2Fo1p2fBse5BaXi2MlkgijimuqvaekQaZ0mHzfzlYggDQ%3D%3D#FAQ_97381) from their ministry of foreign affairs (emphasis mine):

> **How long can I stay in Singapore with a valid e-Visa?**
>
> [...]
>
> A holder of a valid Singapore visa who is found suitable for entry
> into Singapore will be issued with an immigration pass to enter and
> remain in Singapore.   You are advised to check your passport for the
> arrival visit pass endorsement when in Singapore and take note of the
> period of stay granted before leaving the checkpoint.  **The period of
> stay granted is shown on the visit pass endorsement given on your
> passport and it is not tied to the validity of your visa.**

Additionally, a little more information on visa validity comes from this [Singapore tourism website](http://www.globalsingapore.sg/visa-to-singapore/singapore-visa-faq/)

> **14. What is the difference between visa’s validity and the maximum allowed stay in Singapore?**
>
> Please bear in mind that the duration of each stay in Singapore cannot
> exceed 30 days, i.e. every time you are entering the country your
> passport will be accordingly stamped allowing to remain for
> (**usually**) 30 days.